# how to use dataframe apply function with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, textblob

I have a dataframe composed of two columns tweet and lang. I want to extract sentiment based on the language in each row. the language is precised in the second column. I am using "TextBlob" for english and "TextBlobDE" for german. I want to add the sentiment output to another column "subjectivity". Why can't I use something like this?:

```
df["subjectivity"] = df["tweet"].apply(
    lambda tweet: TextBlob(tweet).sentiment.subjectivity
    if df["lang"](tweet) == "en"
    else TextBlobDE(tweet).sentiment.subjectivity
)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

I wanted to use the dataframe power so that I don't iterate over each row
an example of the data I have:

```
tweet,lang
Philadelphia House Cleaning Company Maid Service Direct Launches New Website,en
Boldecker Land fordert mit fünf Jahren Verspätung Geld aus der Kreisschulbaukasse an,de
```

Comment: The error you get is because of wrong syntax in your if statement. `df["lang"](tweet) == "en"` because of the `()` around `"tweet"`  you "call" the Series (which is the column `"tweet"`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df.apply(
    lambda row: TextBlob(row.tweet).sentiment.subjectivity
    if row.lang == "en"
    else TextBlobDE(row.tweet).sentiment.subjectivity,
    axis=1
)
```

Comment: I am getting this error now: TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>

Comment: what is your expected output ? for the subjectivity? I get `0.427` for row 1 and `0.0` for row 2